# QML how to animate every change of a property? (only the last change animation is visible)

Tags: c++, qt, animation, qml, qtquick2

I have to make a mechanical counter controlled from C++. I did it from an image wich contains the digits (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0). Only one digit is visible at a time. I want this counter to change only in one direction (up), and I came up with this theory: if the new digit is smaller than the old one, I first go to the last zero, then disable the animation, go to the first zero, enable animations and finally go to the wanted number. But this wont work.
It moves instantly to the first zero, and then go with animation to the wanted number. Here is the code:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
Window {
    id: mainWindow
    visible: true
    visibility: "Maximized"
    property int digit0Y: 0
    property bool anim0Enabled: true
    Item {
        id: root
        visible: true
        anchors.fill: parent
        Rectangle {
            id: container
            width: 940; height:172
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            clip: true
            color: "black"
            NumberElement {
                id: digit0
                y: mainWindow.digit0Y; x: 0
                animationEnabled: anim0Enabled
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The NumberElement.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
Rectangle {
    id: root
    property bool animationEnabled: true
    width: 130; height: 1892
    color: "transparent"
    Behavior on y {
        enabled: root.animationEnabled
        SmoothedAnimation { velocity: 200; duration: 1500; alwaysRunToEnd: true }
    }
    Image {
        id: digits
        source: "http://s30.postimg.org/6mmsfxdb5/cifre_global.png"
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
#include <QQmlComponent>
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QThread>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlProperty>
#include <QDebug>

int number = 0;
int oldDigit = 0;

void set(QObject *object, int number) {
    int newDigit = number%10;
    if (newDigit < oldDigit) {
        QQmlProperty::write(object, "digit0Y", -1720);
        QQmlProperty::write(object, "anim0Enabled", false);
        QQmlProperty::write(object, "digit0Y", 0);
        QQmlProperty::write(object, "anim0Enabled", true);
    }
    QQmlProperty::write(object, "digit0Y",newDigit*(-172));
    oldDigit = newDigit;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlEngine engine;
    QQmlComponent component(&engine, QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (component.status() == QQmlComponent::Error) {
        qWarning() << component.errorString();
        return 1;
    }
    QObject *object = component.create();
    set(object, 9);
    //QThread::msleep(1000);
    set(object, 1);
    return app.exec();
}
```

Normally a separate class take care of setting the digits, related to some events, but i tried to simplify to demonstrate my problem. In the example above, the digit goes to 1, and dont care about the `set(object, 9)`. That is my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait for the first animation to finish before you start the second one. You might be thinking, "but I set [`alwaysRunToEnd`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-animation.html#alwaysRunToEnd-prop) to `true`...", but that doesn't help here:

> This property holds whether the animation should run to completion when it is stopped.
>
> If this true the animation will complete its current iteration when it is stopped - either by setting the running property to false, or by calling the stop() method.

What's currently happening is that you set `9` as the digit, which tells the animation that it should start animating, but then the next instruction you give is to set `1` as the digit, which tells the animation to stop what it was doing and animate this new change.

In general, handling Qt Quick animations is easier from QML.

I'd also recommend `PathView` for this particular use case, as it might make it easier to achieve what you're after.